# 404 error: "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource". What should I do?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

I've combed through practically every Stack Overflow post I could find and Google to resolve this, but to no avail.  I have set up a Maven project in IntelliJ.

When I try to access localhost:8090 on the browser I get a 404 error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Providing images for a visual.

Here is the artifact setup:

[image: Artifact screenshot]

Here is the Tomcat setup:

[image: Tomcat server tab]

[image: Tomcat deployment tab]

This is the url:

http://localhost:8090/json/product/ping

This is the service code:

```
package com.project.rest;
import com.project.dao.OracleJDBC;
import com.project.product.FiftyInFifty;
import com.project.product.FsiProductLine;
import com.project.product.HHSProductLine;
import com.project.product.WrapProductLine;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Date;

@Path("/json/product")

public class JSONService {

    private FsiProductLine fsi = new FsiProductLine();
    private WrapProductLine wrap = new WrapProductLine();
    private HHSProductLine hhs = new HHSProductLine();
    private DalimGetPropertyValues properties = new 
    DalimGetPropertyValues();

    @GET
    @Path("ping")
    public String getServerTime() {
        System.out.println("RESTful Service 'DalimRestService' is running 
==> ping");
        return "received ping on " + new Date().toString() + "; environmen 
: " + properties.getEnvironemnt();
}}
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.project.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my POM file:

```
<project>

    <artifactId>DalimRestService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <finalName>DalimRestService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.jre10-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>







    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    </properties>
```

I have currently set Tomcat to port 8090.  I know it should be a straightforward thing, but I can't seem to get this to work no matter what I do.

Comment: First two screenshot looks exactly the same to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about that. I made the correction. Just click the Artifact screenshot link and it will take you to the proper screenshot.

Comment: Your title starts _"This is very specific question about a 404 error..."_ but I don't see any question (or question mark) in your post. If your question is simply _"Why am I getting a 404 error?"_ you should update your post to make that clear.

Comment: So what is the URL?  This is not a very specific question.  We need the URL, the web.xml, and what I'm guessing is your service code.

Comment: I would love to make it that clear. Except I'm not allowed to.  It's titled the way I titled it because if I title it "Why am I getting a 404 error?" I am told that the title already exists and the field goes red.   I will add the web.xml, URL and the service code.

Comment: I added the requested things.  Thanks for your help folks. Do let me know if there is more info I can provide.

Comment: @shaldip Add a sentence in the post that ends in a question mark so readers know what your question is! You have supplied a terrific amount of detail, but a post without a question mark does not contain a question; don't force the reader guess.

Comment: @skomisa Ok, I added the sentence with the question mark.